# How to create a UDF in group by clause?

Tags: group-by, dolphindb

Can I use a user-defined function in a `group by` clause? If so, what are the rules or requirements for creating a UDF in such a clause?

Has anyone done this before and can share some experience by providing a simple example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a UDF in a `group by` clause, you must ensure that the UDF will return a vector of the same length as a column in the table.

For example:

```
nano = 21:00:00 + 1..4
price = 100+cumsum(rand(0.02, 4)-0.01)
volume = rand(1000, 4)
symbol = `000001`600000`601766`600519
t=table(symbol, nano, price, volume)
def grpfunc(v): iif(v> 50, 0, 1)
select sum(price) from t group by grpfunc(volume)
// output
```

[image]